# IDE or text editor that really indents everything?

Tags: windows, php, text-editor, ide, code-beautification

I want an IDE or text editor that automatically (when clicking in the indent button) reindents every line of code (from the begining to the end).

For example, Sublime 3 doesn't do this. It just reindents everything based on your position of the cursor when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or (another example) this code:

```
echo "<li id='officeHeader'>
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>
    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-desktop'></i>
    <span class='menu-text'>
        Text
    </span>

    <b class='arrow fa fa-angle-down'></b>
</a>

<b class='arrow'></b>

<ul class='submenu'>
    <li id='navCompany'>
        <a href='#'>
            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-caret-right'></i>
            Text
        </a>

        <b class='arrow'></b>
    </li>

    <li id='navUser'>
        <a href='#'>
            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-caret-right'></i>
            Uses
        </a>

        <b class='arrow'></b>
    </li>

    <li id='navPublication'>
        <a href='#'>
            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-caret-right'></i>
            Public          </a>

        <b class='arrow'></b>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>";
```

Comment: Do you mean *indent*?

Comment: Sublime does support indenting: [reindent shortcut in sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12182896/995714)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to indent my messy code before I make any commit. I have tried this feature in Aptana Studio, Brackets, PHPStorm and Atom. VS Code does it best (in my opinion).

The code you've shared may need to be indented as HTML separately.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin exists for **CudaText** editor. Cross-platform, free.

- menu item Plugins/ Addon Manager/ Install
- choose plugin **HTML Tidy**, install it
- open your HTML file with wrong indent
- call menu Plugins/ HTML Tidy/ Menu, choose "Reformat only"

Answer (score 0):

Almost all IDEs I know do indent everything. Even a text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has a builtin plugin to indent the whole file. I believe [Sublime also supports the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12182896/995714). However if you want another IDE then:

- Eclipse supports autoformat, including [reindent the code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6068009/995714)
- MSVC has a similar feature [with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5755942/995714)